# Producer method with wildcard type

Tags: java, generics, cdi, java-ee-7

I need something simple like this

```
@Produces
@Annotated(Licensed.class) //Qualifier
public Set<Class<?>> getLicensedClasses() {
    return licensed;
}
```

However this does not work. CDI behaves according documentation:

> If a producer field type contains a wildcard type parameter the container automatically detects the problem and treats it as a definition error.

Set in the snippet contains bunch of classes obtained via reflection. It is a set of classes annotated with `@Licensed` annotation.

Comment: "this does not work" can you explain how it's not working a little better? For example, what error or undesired behavior are you seeing?

Comment: CDI refuses this producer method as invalid, because of wildcard generic in the method return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drop the wildcard:

```
@Produces
@Annotated(Licensed.class) //Qualifier
public Set<Class> getLicensedClasses() {
    return licensed;
}
```